# Visual Studio TFS workspace and solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have a problem with my team foundation server whenever I change something in the project and then check it in other visual studio can't see the changes when they get latest version of the file or entire project but the change is available in the Source Control Explorer but not in the solution explorer.
[image]

I use Team Foundation Server 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3):

If the file exists on disk (physically in the folder) but does not show in the solution then it is likely that the file was checked in, but the modification to the solution was not.

On the solution explorer there is a "show all files" button at the top of the page. If you click it you should see the file grayed out. Right click on it and add it to the solution with the "include in project". Now check in the change to the project file.

Everyone will now see it added.

You need to find who is adding files and not checking in the solution. I find a rolled up newspaper is most suitable to rectifying the issue permanently.

Comment: file doesn't exist on the disk but I changed name of the Holiday.cshtml to Duty.cshtml and I checked it in.

Comment: The UI that you have above states that you have the file locally. Have you tried a "get latest" with the overwrite flag?

Comment: Yes same thing I tried both get latest version and get specific version overwrite all

Comment: Then the above answer is true. The files exists on disk but is not added to the solution. Have you checked the physical folder in windows explorer, not just the folder in the Visual Studio Solution explorer?

Comment: I actually had to drag the file from File Explorer into my solution in VS.